# Attempting to create an object of type with an existing primary key value 'not implemented'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I'm trying to store user email address in `Realm` whenever the user hits `Submit` but whenever I do so, I'm getting the error (link below).  I understand that data persists in realm and every time I render, I'm trying to create a new Email object with the same name.

I followed https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#updating-objects (the update section).  Maybe updating will do the trick to fix this issue?  `realm.write()` method is what I'm focusing on.

[error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy9gp.png)

Here's my `.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Third from './Third';

class Second extends Component {
    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'Third' // .js file name
        });
    }

    render() {
        const Realm = require('realm');

        class Email {}
        Email.schema = {
            name: 'Email',
            primaryKey: 'name',
            properties: {
                name: 'string',
            },
        };

        const realm = new Realm({schema: [Email]});

// Query
        let email = realm.objects('Email');
        // email.length // => 0

// Write
        realm.write(() => {
            email = realm.create('Email', {
                name: 'something'
            });

            realm.create('Email', {name: "else"}, true);
        });

        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" email"}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" password"}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20 // makes button horizontally longer.
    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 4

    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#9b42f4',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#41bbf4',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 10
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

export default Second;
```

Comment: The second `realm.create()` is updating an object which has `else` as the value of the primary key.